# Java RMI: Architecture for NOT passing an object, just exposing its methods to a client-side instance

Tags: java, methods, rmi, instantiation, application-server

I've got a large Java-based API and for security reasons I'm trying to divide it into a client-to-application server architecture. I've already determined that there are no so-called "Java Application Servers" (frameworks) extant that can help me here, but if I'm wrong, please point me at one that's not restricted to web-oriented applications. That is, I'm "rolling my own" application server.

The existing API is already accessed via method calls to an instantiated instance of a single "object" that implements what needs to be done.

IIUC (If I understand correctly), I can set up an RMI server that instantiates individual instances of the API object - maybe instantiate a pool of them - and then "hand them" as object instances to inbound RMI calls from clients who ask for an instance. They can then call any methods of that instance, and all the actual processing of those methods happens on the server's side, with any results returned through the RMI mechanism.

So far so good, I think. Now for the tricky part I'd like clarification on, please:

If I've got it right, I further understand that either all the methods and attributes are exposed (via "extends UnicastRemoteObject" or I can restrict the attributes and methods I'd like to have available remotely by creating an intermediary class definition whose methods are all defined in an interface.

Am I correct in understanding that using this approach I can then have my original API as-was, and only need to create this one "encapsulating class" which exposes what needs to be exposed?

And moving to a more advanced design, as instantiation is expensive, I'd like to have a pool of pre-instantiated instances; would I need yet another class that instantiates a bunch of these exposable objects and then "returns" them to a calling client? Or, can I do that somehow within the existing RMI machinery - or within my encapsulating API-Server class itself?

Comment: I'd rather write a prototype instead of asking all those (non-trivial) questions...

Comment: @home - I've actually done that - there's a nice small one here: http://littletutorials.com/2008/07/14/the-10-minutes-getting-started-with-rmi-tutorial/ Trouble is, it's hard sometimes to tell just where the processing is actually happening.

Comment: EJB3 with separate local and remote interfaces sounds like what you want. The container will give you a ton of other useful services as well -  transation management, security, pooling, persistence, and more.

Comment: +1 for Perceptron's answer. If you're concerned about security as you say, you shouldn't be rolling your own application server. You could accomplish that with EJB. You could also accomplish that with a REST (JAX-RS/Jersey) interface fronting either EJB's or just plain Java code.

Answer (score 1):

When you extend `UnicastRemoteObject` (or export a `Remote` object) and implement an interface that extends `Remote`, the methods declared in that `Remote` interface are exposed for remote invocation. When these methods are invoked by a client, the execution of the method takes place on the server. Only data contained in the method result, if any, is exposed to the client.

If you want multiple instances of the remote object, you can bind them in a registry under distinct names, or you can create another remote type that returns instances of your `Remote` service. Here is a simple sketch:

```
interface MyService extends Remote {
  void doStuff() throws RemoteException;
}

interface MyServiceManager extends Remote {
  MyService getService() throws RemoteException;
}
```

You would then bind a single `MyServiceManager` instance in an RMI registry so that clients can find it. The `MyService` instances should not be bound in the registry; anonymous instances will be returned via `MyServiceManager`. Since these objects are also `Remote`, only a stub will be returned to the client, and when the client invokes a method on it, the method will be executed on the server.